# How to use the Transferable protocol in SwiftUI tables

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I am building a macOS app in Swift, using SwiftUI. I have the following struct:

```swift
struct focusArticle: Identifiable {
    let category: String
    let headline: String
    let body: String
    let publishedDate: String
    let source: String
    var id = UUID()
}
```

I have created an array with instances of `focusArticle` that are being used to populate a `Table` element, like so

```swift
struct ArticleView: View {
    @State private var selectedArticles = Set<focusArticle.ID>()

    var body: some View {
        Table(articles, selection: $selectedArticles) {
            TableColumn("Category", value: \.category)
                .width(70)
            TableColumn("Headline", value: \.headline)
                .width(350)
            TableColumn("Published", value: \.publishedDate)
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 200)
    }
}
```

I want to make each row in this table draggable, so I can drag-drop from this table, to a similar table in another view. From reading Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreTransferable/Transferable?changes=_3), it seems like I need to do two things.

1. Make my `focusArticle` struct conform to the `Transferable` protocol.
2. Use the `.draggable` modifier on the table to make the elements draggable.

I can't seem to do either of these things. Copying over the example code from the documentation into my struct makes it throw an error — `Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'String' conform to 'TransferRepresentation'`. Adding a `.draggable` modifier to the table throws an expected error: `Instance method 'draggable' requires that '[focusArticle]' conform to 'Transferable'`

EDIT: This is one of the ways I have tried to make `focusArticles` confirm to Transferable.

```swift
struct focusArticle: Identifiable, Codable, Transferable {
    let category: String
    let headline: String
    let body: String
    let publishedDate: String
    let source: String
    var id = UUID()
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .focusArticle)
    }
}
```

This shows an error `Type 'UTType' has no member 'focusArticle'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a UTType, as an extension like this:

```
extension UTType {
    static var focusArticle = UTType(exportedAs: "com.yourdomain.yourapp.focusarticle")
}
```